# Is There A Way to Manipulate Values in a Cucumber Data Table?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I have a feature test written something like this.

```
Given I am a Bank Customer
And My Starting Balances Are 
| Account Type | Balance |
| Checking     | 98.00   |
When on Day 1 I make DOLLAR AMT withdrawal from my existing balances
| Account Type | Balance |
| Checking     | 98.00   |
```

What I want to do is take the integer amount and subtract it from the balance, and then reassign that value to the data table and pass it on.

I know I can get the value from the table, assign it to a variable, and manipulate it. I need to put the updated value back into it.

EDIT - Here is what I have so far. It calculates the new balance, but I need to reinsert that value into the DT.

```
 public void myUpdatedCheckingBalance(int cashAmt, DataTable balances) throws Throwable {
    List<List<String>> balanceData = balances.raw();
    String origBal;
    int updatedBal = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<balanceData.size(); i++){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, balanceData.get(i).get(i));
    origBal = balanceData.get(i).get(i);
    int balValue = Integer.parseInt(origBal);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, balValue);
    updatedBal = balValue - hoursAmt;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, updatedBal);
    balanceData.set(arg0, arg1)
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, updatedBal);
```

Comment: Why do you capitalize the first letter of every word in the title? It's distracting.

Comment: The backing list of the datatable is set to unmodifiable. You will need to create another list of list of strings manually by looping the existing one. U can modify te new one any way u want.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber works best when you write simple scenarios that express intent, that is WHAT you are doing and WHY its important. Anything involved in HOW something is done is better off elsewhere.

One solution to your problem is just to write simpler scenarios that express the intent. For example

```
Scenario: Withdraw all the money in my account
  Given I have an account with some money in it
  When I withdraw all my money
  Then my account should have no money in it

Scenario: Withdraw more money than my account holds
  Given I have an account with some money in it
  When I withdraw more money than my account has
  Then ...

  ...
```

You will probably need several scenarios to explore accounts, overdraft limits and balances. What you don't need to do here is put in values. Cukes are for trying to define the business rules of how an account behaves, not the technical rules. So you talk about your `overdraft limit` and `balance` but don't use figures unless they specifically add to the clarity of the scenario (tip: they never do, you can always write a better scenario without examples, as all examples require explanation as to what they are an example off).